# Scala's eval in eclipse plugin development

Tags: eclipse, scala, plugins, eval

Now, I develop an eclipse plugin using scala.

In this plugin, I want to use util-eval library which is created by twitter.

(https://github.com/twitter/util/tree/master/util-eval)

I tried to build this library by using 'sbteclipse', got jars(such as util-core-5.3.13.jar and util-eval-5.3.13), and added following build pathes:

```
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="jars/util-core-5.3.13.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="jars/util-eval-5.3.13.jar"/>
```

Here is a sample test code:

```
class SampleTest {
@Test
def evalTest(): Unit = {
    val ret = (new com.twitter.util.Eval).apply[(Int => Int)]("{(x:Int) => x*2}")
    println(ret(4))
}
```

}

When running as Run -> JUnit Test, it works (displaying "8")

But, when running as Run -> EclipseApplication -> (execute plugin), it doesn't work and I got some errors.
Here is a plugin (handler) code:

```
class SampleHandler extends AbstractHandler{
def execute(event: ExecutionEvent): Object = {
    val ret = (new com.twitter.util.Eval).apply[(Int => Int)]("{(x:Int) => x*2}")
    println(ret(4))
            return null:
}
 }
```

and here is a error messages:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable lo load scala interpreter from classpath (scala-compiler jar is missing?)
at com.twitter.util.Eval.liftedTree1$1(Eval.scala:77)
at com.twitter.util.Eval.com$twitter$util$Eval$$compilerPath(Eval.scala:73)
at com.twitter.util.Eval$StringCompiler.<init>(Eval.scala:429)
at com.twitter.util.Eval.compiler(Eval.scala:110)
at com.twitter.util.Eval.compile(Eval.scala:219)
at evaltest.handlers.SampleHandler.execute(SampleHandler.scala:25)
```

I got some other error messages which displayed with 'red' font:

```
when processing type mungers evaltest.handlers.SampleHandler
when processing type mungers 
when weaving 
[Xlint:cantFindType]
[eval_test_plugin] error can't determine modifiers of missing type    
org.eclipse.jdt.ui.SharedASTProvider$WAIT_FLAG
when processing type mungers evaltest.handlers.SampleHandler
when processing type mungers 
when weaving 
...
```

Simply, I want to create an plugin that interpret scala script inputted from plugin user and execute the script.
In order realize that, 'eval' feature is essential.

So, please let me know some solution.

Comment: Are you sure you have scala-**compiler** jar on the classpath?

Comment: I edited as follows:
Configure Build Path -> Add Library -> Scala Library, Scala Compiler
Is this not sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have dependency on `org.scala-ide.scala.compiler` under `Require-Bundle` in your `MANIFEST.MF` file.

Comment: I checked and added org.scala-ide.scala.compiler, but it doesn't work (error messages are still displaying)
Here is Require-BUndle section in my MANIFEST.MF:
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility;bundle-version="3.2.100",
 org.eclipse.text;bundle-version="3.5.101",
 org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring;bundle-version="3.5.201",
 org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring;bundle-version="3.6.0",
 org.eclipse.jface.text;bundle-version="3.7.2",
 org.eclipse.jdt.core;bundle-version="3.7.3",
 org.junit;bundle-version="4.8.2",
 org.scala-ide.scala.compiler;bundle-version="2.9.2"